# Custom Drupal-8 module doesn't appear

Tags: php, symfony, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I have successfully installed my own module on Drupal8 site. I tried to access it by entering path specified in routing.yml file but I'm getting 'Page not Found' error. I'm almost sure that my module is written correctly(I was following a tutorial where the same module where accessed successfully). What could cause my issue and how can I solve it?

here are my module files:
1)kalvis.info.yml

```
name: 'Kalvis'
description: 'My module'
type: 'module'
core: 8.x
```

2)kalvis.routing.yml

```
kalvis.content:
    path: /kalvis/{$from}/{$to}
    defaults:
        _content: 'Drupal\kalvis\Controller\kalvisController::content'
        _title: 'My module'
    requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

3)kalvisController.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\kalvis\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
class kalvisController extends ControllerBase{
    public function content($to, $from)
    {
        $message = $this->t('%from sends message %to', [
            '%from' => $from,
            '%to' => $to,
        ]);
        return $message;
    }
}
?>
```

Here is how I'm storing those module files:

```
www/drupal8/modules/kalvis
                    kalvis.info.yml
                    kalvis.routing.yml
                    /src/Controller
                        kalvisController.php
```

I tried to access module by entering URL's like http://localhost/drupal8/admin/kalvis/Kalvis/Drupal and http://localhost/drupal8/kalvis/Kalvis/Drupal but still get the same problem.

I'm using Drupal 8.0.0 beta10 installed on localhost(WAMP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the routing yml file add the single quotation marks around the value for your path. Also remove the `$` sign from the 2 parameters.

Since **beta 4** of Drupal 8 you have to specify the path as `_controller` which should return a render array.

**kalvis.routing.yml** file as:

```
kalvis.content:
  path: '/kalvis/{from}/{to}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\kalvis\Controller\kalvisController::content'
    _title: 'My module'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

in your **kalvisController.php**, change the return value to a render array `return array('#markup' => $message);`