# Drupal 8 Module Not Found

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457473/why-is-my-drupal-8-module-show-page-not-found) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372745/custom-drupal-8-module-doesnt-appear) which both had similar problems, but the selected answers didn't work for me.

I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/add-a-routing-file) to create my own custom Dupral 8 module. From what I can tell, I have the right file stucture and correct content in my files, but I get a page not found error. I have tried using leading slahes on the `_controller` in the photoshelter.routing.yml file and in the namespace declarations in the PhotoController.php file, but that hasn't changed anything. I have run out of ideas to try. Does anyone have any trouble shooting suggestions of spot errors in these files?

**PhotoController.php**

```
namespace Drupal\photoshelter\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class PhotoController extends ControllerBase {
  public function content() {
    return array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $this->t('Hello, World!'),
    );
  }
}
```

**photoshelter.info.yml**

```
name: PhotoShelter API
description: Integrate the PhotoShelter API with your Drupal site.
package: Custom
type: module
core: 8.x
configure: photoshelter.settings
php: 5.6
```

**photoshelter.routing.yml**

```
photoshelter.content:
  path: '/photoshelter'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\photoshelter\Controller\PhotoController::content'
    _title: 'PhotoShelter API'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

**File Structure**

```
photoshelter
  -src
    -Controller
      PhotoController.php
  info/routing.yml files
```

Comment: That code looks totally fine. Did you clear cache after enabling your module? Do you see any errors in the logs when you hit the path or when clearing cache?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your files into a fresh Drupal 8 install and it works.

Make sure the .routing file is in the top level of your module folder.

Make sure you clear cache after.